# What is the transpose of Lorentz transformation under spinor representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-matrices

Let $S$ be the Lorentz transfortmation under spinor representation, and from any quantum field theory textbooks, we know that
$$
S^\dagger=\gamma^0S^{-1}\gamma^0 \\
S^{-1}=\gamma^0S^\dagger\gamma^0
$$

where $\gamma^\mu$ is Dirac matrices ($\mu=0,1,2,3$).

**The question that confused me is that how are $S^T$ and {$S， S^\dagger, S^{-1}, \gamma^\mu$} related?**

Comment: In this question,  $\gamma^0$  is hermitian

Comment: @Dan Yand  I want to analyze the properties of $\psi^T \gamma^\mu C \psi$  under Lorentz tramsformation,  where  $C=i\gamma_0\gamma_2$, and $\psi$ is spinor.  At this situation,  we are going to encounter $S^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it depends on which $4\times 4$ matrix representation is used.

In *any* representation, as far as its action on a Dirac spinor $\psi$ is concerned, the connected part of the Lorentz group is generated by transformations of the form
$$
\psi\rightarrow
   S
\psi
\hskip2cm
S = \exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\right)
\tag{1}
$$
with $\mu\neq \nu$. This is a Lorentz boost if $\mu=0$ or $\nu=0$, and it is an ordinary rotation if $\mu\geq 1$ and $\nu\geq 1$.

Now suppose that we use a representation in which $\gamma^\mu$ is

- hermitian for $\mu=0$ and anti-hermitian for $\mu =1,2,3$
- symmetric for $\mu=0,2$ and anti-symmetric for $\mu=1,3$

The representation used in Peskin and Schroeder's *An Intro to QFT* satisfies these conditions. In this representation, the matrix
$$
 C\propto \gamma^0\gamma^2
\tag{2}
$$
satisfies
$$
 (\gamma^\mu)^T C = -C\gamma^\mu,
\tag{3}
$$
which implies
$$
 S^T C = C S^{-1}.
\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, under the Lorentz transformation $\psi\rightarrow S\psi$, the quantity $\psi^T C\psi$  transforms as a scalar:
$$
 \psi^T C\psi\rightarrow \psi^T S^T CS\psi = \psi^T C\psi
\tag{5}
$$
and the quantity $\psi^T C\gamma^\mu\psi$ transforms as a vector:
$$
 \psi^T C\gamma^\mu\psi\rightarrow \psi^T S^T C\gamma^\mu S\psi 
 = \psi^T C (S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S)\psi.
\tag{6}
$$
By the way, the similar-looking quantity $\psi^T \gamma^\mu C\psi$ 
transforms like this:
$$
 \psi^T \gamma^\mu C\psi\rightarrow \psi^T S^T \gamma^\mu CS\psi 
 = \psi^T S^T \gamma^\mu (S^T)^{-1}C\psi,
\tag{7}
$$
which is *not* the way a vector (or any other tensor) should transform.

In any representation, we can think of (4) as the defining condition for a matrix $C$. The matrix $C$ that satisfies this condition depends on the representation; but if such a matrix exists, then equations (5)-(6) hold automatically. We can think of equations (5)-(6) as the *motive* for the condition (4).

Similarly, if we choose a matrix $A$ so that
$$
 S^\dagger A = A S^{-1},
\tag{8}
$$
then the quantity $\psi^\dagger A\psi$ transforms as a scalar:
$$
 \psi^\dagger A\psi\rightarrow
  \psi^\dagger S^\dagger AS\psi = \psi^\dagger A\psi
\tag{9}
$$
and the quantity $\psi^\dagger A\gamma^\mu\psi$ transforms as a vector:
$$
 \psi^\dagger A\gamma^\mu\psi\rightarrow 
  \psi^\dagger S^\dagger A\gamma^\mu S\psi 
 = \psi^\dagger A (S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S)\psi.
\tag{10}
$$
We can think of equations (9)-(10) as the *motive* for the condition (8). In the representation described above, the familiar choice $A\propto\gamma^0$ satisfies the condition (8), but this depends on the representation.

Comment: Why does eq.(2) satisfy eq.(3)?

Comment: @StephenWong In the given representation, eq (2) says that $C$ is the product of the two symmetric $\gamma$-matrices. If $\gamma^\mu$ is one of these matrices, then it anti-commutes with $C$ (because it commutes with itself and anti-commutes with the other $\gamma$-matrix in $C$); and since it is symmetric, this $\gamma^\mu$ satisfies eq (3). If $\gamma^\mu$ is one of the anti-symmetric matrices, then it anti-commutes with _both_ of the $\gamma$-matrices in $C$ because it is distinct from both of them, so it commutes with $C$. Since this $\gamma^\mu$ is anti-symmetric, it again satisfies (3).

Comment: I see. Could you explain that  how did you get the equation (4) ?

Comment: $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu C=-(\gamma^\mu C)(\gamma^\nu)^T=-(-C(\gamma^\mu)^T(\gamma^\nu)^T=C(\gamma^\mu)^T(\gamma^\nu)^T$   Is it like this ?

Comment: why could you get eq.(4)  from $(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)^TC=C(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @StephenWong  My apologies -- the way I wrote equation (3) before was confusing even though it was correct. I edited the post so that the transposed $\gamma$-matrices are now on the left-hand side of equation (3). This new version of equation (3) is still correct and can still be deduced using the logic in my previous comment. Using the new version: $(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)^TC=(\gamma^\nu)^T(\gamma^\mu)^TC=C\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=-C\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$. Much more clear this way! Sorry about that.